# How to enter manager mode on Aruba 8320 switch?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

```
tasks:
      - name: Enable mode
        aruba_command:
          provider:
            username: "{{ username_switch }}"
            password: "{{ password_switch }}"
          commands:
            - enable
```

Unfortunately, the job fails and returns this output:

```
 "ansible_facts": {
         "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
  },
     "msg": "enable\r\nInvalid input: enable\r\nxxxx1-xx-xx-HPC8320-1# " }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ansible that is a concept known as ["become"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/become.html#become-and-network-automation) and is not a *command* that you send but rather a state of the conection

Even if ansible did what you said and ran `enable`, it would lose its effect after that task completed because you would disconnect from the device and lose your `enable`-ness. By setting `become: yes` and the correct authentication vars, you enable ansible to elevate its privileges as every time it connects, which enables fun things like retries and decomposing your playbook into smaller parts that are more logically grouped, without having to deal with the "be sure to run `enable` before doing ..." parts